# How to attach to a cross compiled go binary for debugging purposes using the Visual Studio Code IDE?

Tags: linux, go, visual-studio-code, cross-compiling

I am using Visual Studio Code as the ide for a golang based application. The application will run on a linux target. I want to attach the VSC debugger to this cross compiled binary. The binary could be compiled for both arm or x86 platforms. I am aware of a launch.json file that can make this possible but I have never used it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger *dlv* is used for debugging go code. *Delve* or *dlv* has a limitation it can only attach to a binary with 64 bit architecture. Hence, I compiled my code for 64 bit amd architecture and ran it on my linux machine. Next, I fetched process id of my binary and attached delve onto it. I used a port 2345 for the delve server

*dlv attach some_process_id --listen=:2345 --headless --api-version=2 --log*

You might also need to enable/change debugging level on the linux target under sudo privileges.

*cat 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope*

On the Visual studio code IDE create a *launch.json* with below settings:

```
{
            "name": "Launch Windows",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            "remotePath": "path/to/binary",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "target ip address"
 }
```

Since I was running Visual Studio from a windows machine I chose the mode as remote for the remote linux target.

Now run the debugger from visual studio code and the settings from launch.json will look for the dlv debugger/server on the target and attach to it. Put some break points in the code preferably at places which can be triggered externally. eg. on a server accept call that can be triggered from a client call.